# Previous Selector In jQuery of unmatched control type

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox wrapped around by a Label. Need to access text of that label.

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox">
   NeedThisText
</label>
```

I tried this but seems not to be working (returning blank)

```
$(this).prev('label').text()
```

Above code comes in the mapped function like this:

```
 var sThisVal = $('#chkDC :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                    return $(this).prev('label').text() + ',';
                }).get();
```

So my intention is basically select all Selected Texts

Comment: Whats `this`? `.text()` will work see http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vcx2vs32/

Comment: if `this` is the input element then `$(this).parent('label').text()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EmpWV/

Comment: Thanks Arun. .parent did it. I was thinking in terms of prev and prevall siblings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lbl = $(document).find("label");

var text = $(lbl).children[1];
```

or if ur label have an id do it this way :

```
var lbl = $("#labelid");

var text = $(lbl).children[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

To select value inside label :

```
 <label>
       <input type="checkbox">
       NeedThisText
    </label>
```

this is most better way to do that task:

```
  var requiredvalue=$('label').text();
  console.log(requiredvalue);
alert(requiredvalue);
```

click this fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/govindajs/eqjvtwvs/2/

Comment: Yes, but I have more then 300 labels with no id's :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<label id="labelid">
   <input type="checkbox">
   NeedThisText
</label>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#labelid').text();
```

Comment: $('#labelid').html(); will take checkbox too, he just want the text.

Comment: Also, these labels are build on the fly, dont have access to its Id's

Answer (score 0):

```
<label id="label1">
```

NeedThisText

```
$('#label1').text();
```

you need to call a id or class to show text

Answer (score 0):

Actually the HTML Markup should be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>
   NeedThisText
</label>
```

But in your case, you can use this to get your label text (tested):

```
var label = $('label').text();
var text  = label.trim();
alert(text);
```